# Print the position of the sentences with forEach JAVA. where am i wrong in the loop?

Tags: java, algorithm

```
public static void componiPoesia(String outputFile, String[] frasi) {
    try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(
            new FileOutputStream(new File(outputFile), true))) {

        int count = 0;
        for (String frase : frasi) {
            pw.print(frase + ". ");
            count++;
            pw.print("\n" + count);
        }
        pw.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error writing into the outputFile: " + outputFile);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

*This is what should come out

```
ChiHaRobaInMareNonHaNulla. TuttiIPiuGrandiPensieriSonoConcepitiMentreSiCammina. 
2, 1
```

This is what comes out of me

```
ChiHaRobaInMareNonHaNulla. 
1TuttiIPiuGrandiPensieriSonoConcepitiMentreSiCammina. 
2
```

Comment: you do understand we have no idea what the input is, right?

Comment: ChiHaRobaInMareNonHaNulla. TuttiIPiuGrandiPensieriSonoConcepitiMentreSiCammina. 
2, 1 this is the  
quite right

Comment: Do you mean you expect this, or is this the content of that file?

Comment: yes I expect this

Comment: yes, that we understood. But we have no idea what your input is.

Comment: what more do you need?

Comment: If you want to *first* print the words, *then* print the numbers, then you'll need **two loops**. Since you didn't specify why you wanted to print `2, 1` in that order, we can't help much with how the second loop should look.

Comment: in fact I'm stuck I don't understand how to go on

Comment: What does the string array frasi contain? That is what @Stultuske is also expecting to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one, As your code **pw.print("\n" + count);** brek your line so i make it outside loop and done some changes in your code for expecting output.

```
     try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter( new FileOutputStream(new File(outputFile), true))) {

            int count = 0;
            String temp="";
            for (String frase : frasi) {
                pw.print(frase + ". ");
                if(count==0)
                temp=(frasi.length-count)+"";
                else
                 temp=temp+","+(frasi.length-count);
                count++;
            }
            pw.print("\n" + temp);
            pw.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            //System.out.println("Error writing into the outputFile: " + outputFile);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: It works for the first input, but not for the others.

Comment: @andrea chiellino what about other input. As you have not provided enough lead in your question so answer is as per your expectaion. These things are asked by other peoples and you said you are expecting the result only . Please edit your post with sufficient information.

Comment: Thanks for participating in the end I solved. Thank you

Comment: @andreachiellino Best of Luck frend!!..hope this answer help you ..please upvote if it is?

Comment: Yes, yes Thank you Kandy.

Answer (score 0):

According to the expected output, I suppose, that you have to print the phrases to the file (from the String[] frasi array) in the for each loop and count the number of phrases. You don't have to print counter in for-each loop. After the loop you can do something like:

```
while(counter > 0)
{
  pw.print(counter);
  counter--;
  if(counter > 0)
     pw.print(", ");
}
```